# how to add three custom fields to jomsocial events

Tags: jomsocial

I need to add a few custom fields to the events on my JomSocial site.

I can adjust the DB - this is no problem - but if anyone has any ideas on which files need to be adjusted to accommodate the extra entries I would be most grateful

Many thanks in advance